# How to get click event in React HLSPlayer?

Tags: reactjs

In my React project, I have a video plugin to play m3u8 files which is React HLSPlayer.

I want to add a click event on that plugin, for some conditions to render. What could be the appropriate solution?

```
const clickFunction = () => {
  console.log("Clicked");
};

<ReactHlsPlayer
  url={data.video.url}
  autoplay={false}
  onClick={clickFunction}
  controls={true}
  width="100%"
  height="auto"
  config={{
    file: {
      forceHLS: true,
    },
  }}
/>;
```

As there is no output with `onClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this syntax :

```
 const clickFunction = () => {
    console.log('Clicked')
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ReactHlsPlayer
    onClick={()=>{clickFunction()}}
    url='https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8'
    autoplay={false}
    controls={true}
    width={500}
    height={375}
/>
```

Be caution that your click event will only be trig when you click on the movie "screen"
[sandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-monad-zbh7w?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: the sandbox link was wrong I updated my answer and it works... is this your component structure?

Comment: OK its working now in your sandbox... I don't know why mine is not working

Comment: Yes its working now... some minor mistake from my side